# Read and Write operations get bad fd and no such file

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I have this C program.
I have two processes, father and son, and use semaphores to make them synchronize one at time. 
The father has to write (n) numbers, ten in this case, always in the first byte of the opened file and the son has to read it.
The problem is that when I print the results, I get bad file descriptor for the write (father) and no such file for the read(the son).
Can you help me, please?? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define FILENAME "test.txt"
#define MUTEX "/mutex"
#define READ "/read"
#define WRITE "/write"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i, pid, n=10, fd, x;
    int nread, nwrite;
    char c = 'a';
    sem_t *mutex, *reader, *writer;

    //fd = open(FILENAME, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    mutex = sem_open(MUTEX, O_CREAT, 0666, 1);
    reader = sem_open(READ, O_CREAT, 0666, 0);
    writer = sem_open(WRITE, O_CREAT, 0666, 1);
    pid = fork();
    fd = open(FILENAME, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
    if(fd < 0){
        perror("Open FILE error");
        exit(-1);}
    if(pid == 0){   // son
        do{
            sem_wait(reader);    // si può leggere???
            sem_wait(mutex);
            lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
            nread = read(fd, &x, sizeof(int));
            if(nread <=0)
                perror("Read error");
            printf("Son has read (%d byte) = %d\n", nread, x);
            fflush(NULL);
            sem_post(mutex);
            sem_post(writer);
        }
        while(x != (n-1));
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            sem_wait(writer);  // can I write??
            sem_wait(mutex);
            lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
            nwrite = write(fd, &c, sizeof(char));
            if(nwrite <= 0)
                perror("nwrite error");
            printf("Father has written (%d byte) %d\n", nwrite, i);
            fflush(NULL);
            sem_post(mutex);
            sem_post(reader);    // it's possible to read
        }
        //wait(NULL);
    }
    sem_unlink(MUTEX);
    sem_unlink(READ);
    sem_unlink(WRITE);
    //remove(FILENAME);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `mmap` or pipes for your purpose. And..using `father` and `son` instead of `parent` and `child` is kinda...chauvinistic.

Comment: Ok for father and son. But I need to use a file to write the numbers.

Comment: Please read http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mmap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you opened the file without specifying an *o_flag*.  That's actually undefined behavior (["*Applications shall specify exactly one of .... O_RDONLY .... O_WRONLY .... O_RDWR*"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html)), but for practical purposes means the file was opened *read only*.

Thus the parent's write operation fails with EBADF.  Can't write to a read only file!

Second, the child's error checking is incorrect.  [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) may return zero on success, in which case `errno`, consulted by `perror()`, is not guaranteed to be meaningful.  You mean to check for a return value of less than zero, not of less than or equal to zero.

Comment: Ok. You are right. 
fd = open(FILENAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0600) is the correct piece of code. Unfortunately, I forgot that one of the following access modes should included in the flags: O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR.
Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `open()` call is opening the file for read only.  You have:

```
fd = open(FILENAME, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
```

Because you don't explicitly say `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`, and because the traditional value for `O_RDONLY` is 0, you are effectively opening the file read-only.

The `0777` permissions are suspect too.  You are not creating an executable; you should not be giving the file executable permissions.  In my book, you probably shouldn't be giving others write permission on the file.  In fact, I'd probably go with `0600` permissions.

Comment: I should have added O_RDWR to the flags. Solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your program is a bit strange.

First off, you are asking for trouble by having parent and child processes race to be the one to create the target file.  It would be better for the parent to create and open the file *before* forking, and for (only) the child to open it after.  Be aware that in that case the child should first close (its copy of) the file descriptor opened by the parent.  Alternatively, the way you're doing things, if the parent opened the file then it would probably be sufficient for the child to just use the file descriptor it inherits, without opening the file itself at all.

With that said, it would be more usual for parent and child processes to communicate via a pipe than via a physical file.  That has the particular advantage that you do not need to synchronize access via a semaphore; ordinary blocking I/O does the job.

Additionally, I don't see what your `mutex` semaphore is doing for you.  Even with a design that requires you to manually synchronize writing and reading, it looks like your `reader` and `writer` semaphores will serve that purpose without help.

Importantly, your parent process is writing in `sizeof(char)`-byte uints, whereas your child process is trying to read in `sizeof(int)`-byte units.  This is unlikely to have the result you want.

Furthermore, the `read()` and `write()` functions may return successfully without having transferred the full number of bytes requested (unless that number is `1` and the file is open in blocking mode).  You need to account for that by being prepared to use multiple I/O operations to transfer multi-byte data, if necessary.

Finally, it would be best for just one process to unlink your semaphores.  It is ok for that to happen while the other process is still running.